# How to make a generic struct to contain any CSS properties' values

Tags: css, c, parsing

I want to write my own simplified CSS parser for my own purposes. It have to recognize a few properties (not all of them, of course). So, I projected the architecture, and now want to project the minor details.

Right now I need to create the universal structure which can contain the value of any CSS property. I thought about union with structs for every possibly processing property, but it looks like square wheel for me - there are ~146 different properties (I want to provide support for only about 20-40, but that doesn't matter) - so I will need to create a union with 146 different structures and moreover describe this structures. My project is about 60 KB right now, I don't want to make it grow up to 60 MB yet.

I thought about char value[255], but it makes a limit for every value to be less then 255 (or N) symbols. What can I do to solve this little problem?

Comment: Dynamic memory allocation?

Comment: @MrLister, do you mean to have a pointer to dynamic memory block and interpret the data as the function like CSSBorder(int * block) will need?

Comment: Maybe changing to c++ is an option.

Comment: Actually I just meant to use realloc instead of a fixed char[255]. Most browsers are written in C++ and use std::vectors and std::strings to their fullest extent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One (rather simple) way would be to approach it like so

```
struct CSS {
    char *property;
    char *value;
}
```

Then, while parsing a CSS doc or whatever way you want to fill it, allocate the structure with malloc.

You could on top/aside from that include a linked list, so that when you want to free the allocated memory you simply walk through the list and free all the allocated char* variables. The struct could then look like this:

```
struct CSS_property {
    char *property;
    char *value;
    struct CSS_property *next;
}
```

Where next would contain a pointer to the next struct if there is one or NULL if there ain't

Finally, I suppose you'd need a type to hold the matcher. Maybe it could look like this:

```
struct CSS_matcher {
    char *matcher;
    struct CSS_property *properties;
    struct CSS_matcher *next;
}
```

The properties pointer would point to the first property of this block, the CSS_matcher could in itself be yet another linked list for all matchers you'd encounter in a CSS file.

I'm not familiar with the right CSS terminology, I'm sure they don't actually call matchers matchers...